# Cannot initiate this tooltip inside a <li> tag. Why?

Tags: jquery-plugins, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I cannot initiate this tooltip. My header has got links to Bootstrap and JQuery, but below still doesn't present any tooltip when I hover the trigger text:

```
<li class="col-md-3 port-feature">Harbor Size 
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="code key...">
<i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>

<script> $(document).ready(function(){ 
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
     container: "body",
});
</script></li>
```

Can anyone of you help me out?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    container: "body"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<li class="col-md-3 port-feature">Harbor Size
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="code key...">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">test</i>
  </a>
</li>
```

it work

Comment: Thanks for this, but strangely it doesn't work. Can I send you the page link of the URL in a private message?

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work.... I will send you a link of the URL in a private message.